# Rich Text Comparison in Sharepoint List 2010

Tags: rich-text

I want to compare two rich text fields in sharepoint list form. And also highlight the difference between the textfields data. Is it possible to do this with Sharepoint Designer 2010 itself? or else suggest me the Javascript to do the same.

Thanks in Advance!...